# How does java kafka consumer class handle partitioning?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I basically have a system with multiple tasks of a spring boot application using the Kafka consumer class running with the same consumer group id. They are all connected to the same topic. I didn’t assign any partitioning logic. So I want to understand how this will be handled. Will the Kafka broker automatically assign partitions to individual tasks or will each instance consume from all the partitions?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using group management, and not assigning the partitions yourself, the broker will perform the assignments. Only one consumer in the same group can consume from a partition. When another consumer starts or stops, the broker will rebalance the partitions across the new set of consumers.

Comment: Yes all I am doing is subscribing to the topic with the same group Id. I have about 8 tasks running and 8 partitions so its safe to assume that each task might be consuming from a different partition right?

Comment: Yes; only one active consumer can consume from a partition. There is no "might"; "...each task **will**...". `> about 8` If you drop down to 7, one consumer will consume from two partitions. If you go up to 9, one consumer will be idle.

Comment: Okay thank you!